# Failed upgrade from 12.04 to 13.10

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

I tried updating my ubuntu today from 12.04 to 13.10 and am now unable to update anything and have what is basically a useless system. Whenever I try to launch update manager I get not all updates can be installed, run a partial upgrade

Cannot upgrade

An upgrade from 'raring' to 'precise' is not supported with this tool.

When I try things from terminal they're no better. When trying apt-get update I get an

```
W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/au.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_saucy_multiverse_i18n_Translation-en  Encountered a section with no Package: header

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Trying to run apt-get upgrade gives me

You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libdrm2 : Breaks: libdrm2:i386 (!= 2.4.43-0ubuntu0.2) but 2.4.43-0ubuntu0.0.3 is installed
 libdrm2:i386 : Breaks: libdrm2 (!= 2.4.43-0ubuntu0.0.3) but 2.4.43-0ubuntu0.2 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.

and trying apt-get -f install 

dpkg: error processing libdrm2:i386 (--configure):
 libdrm2:i386 2.4.43-0ubuntu0.0.3 cannot be configured because libdrm2:amd64 is in a different version (2.4.43-0ubuntu0.2)
dpkg: error processing libdrm2 (--configure):
 libdrm2:amd64 2.4.43-0ubuntu0.2 cannot be configured because libdrm2:i386 is in a different version (2.4.43-0ubuntu0.0.3)
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 libdrm2:i386
 libdrm2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu recommends up-gradation only to it's immediate successor like 12.04 to 12.10, 12.10 to 13.04 etc.

You better reinstall 13.10 in your pc instead of upgrading thrice.

Comment: This is not true in general. Besides upgrades from one LTS to another, other upgrades from a supported release to a later supported release that *skip over unsupported releases* are also typically supported and even automatically offered. See [Why does `do-release-upgrade` skip a version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/719465/why-does-do-release-upgrade-skip-a-version)