# Upgrading Ubuntu from 14.04.6 LTS to Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: upgrade

Upgrading Ubuntu from 14.04.6 LTS to Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

My current Ubuntu version details:

```
:~$ cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.6 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
:~$
```

Please suggest me best way to upgrade it to the latest version of Ubuntu(Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS).

Comment: Reinstall it is too big a jump.

Comment: You haven't said if this is a desktop or server install.  Myself I'd *upgrade via re-install*, but I'd evaluate your packages & installed programs (what data-files matter to you) to ensure no issues will occur due to skipped release (this is unlikely (issues are usually when you go backwards); but I'd still do the homework to be sure).  You won't lose data with the **no format** install I'm recommending and have Ubuntu packages added re-installed automatically (if available in Ubuntu repositories) but I'd still backup, and server apps may need data restores.

Comment: FYI:  In my prior comment I suggested how I'd do it (esp. if it's a desktop install), however as you'll be going well outside of what is QA-tested; the most appropriate response is still the *Can I skip over releases when upgrading* which is why I've marked this a duplicate of that question.

Comment: If you'd like to read an answer of a like question I've written, maybe refer to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1166299/how-can-i-upgrade-from-17-04-to-the-latest-non-lts-ubuntu