# Upgrading from 18.04 to 19.10 to fix Internet Issue

Tags: 18.04, kernel, internet

I am currently running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. Recently, my laptop crashed during a Kernel upgrade (I did it via `apt update` then `apt dist-upgrade`). I then ran `dpkg --configure -a` after it told me that I had broken the automatic update process.

Afterward, I ran `apt update && apt dist-upgrade && apt autoremove`, which I always do, but I guess for that reason I can't revert back to the older Kernel version.
It ran fine, but since reboot, my Internet doesn't work anymore. It's not the wifi adapter, which is a common issue. Also, LAN doesn't work - the cable is shown as unplugged.

I figured, since updating the system/installing an older Kernel version Etc. is gonna mess up the tweaks I made to my system over time anyway (Is that correct?), I might as well update to Ubuntu 19.10, which I can do directly from 18.04, right? Which should hopefully fix the issue. Do you share my optimism about that helping?

Comment: i do not think you can upgrade 18.04 directly to 19.10,but  if you wait until the release of 20.04 you can.18.04 is LTS so it can be upgraded directly to the next LTS 20.04.

Comment: @trond hansen: Does that mean, I would have to go from 18.04 to 18.10 to 19.04 to 19.10? Im afraid, the Internet issue is kind of urgent, so I don't want to wait another six months

Comment: you can take a look here to see what options you have https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading it is an old Q&A but it is a good place to start looking for information.

Comment: i do not know if this might solve your internet problem,it depends on what was wrong in the first place(you have two questions here and i think you need to look at them separately).

Comment: @MarkusGratis You don't have to go from 18.04 LTS to 18.10, and in fact it is no longer supported to do so (though you might manage to do it). The reason is that 18.10 has reached end-of-life, even though 18.04 LTS still supported. (18.10 reached EOL before 18.04 LTS because 18.04 LTS is a long term support release.) Because 18.10 is EOL but 18.04 LTS and 19.04 are supported, upgrading 18.04 LTS directly to 19.04 is supported. To get to 19.10, you can do that, and *then* upgrade to 19.10. See [Why does \`do-release-upgrade\` skip a version?](https://askubuntu.com/q/719465/22949) for details.